# Checking for variable change using infinite loop

Tags: java, android

I need to check when the value of a variable is changed in my activity by a service so that I can then update the UI with the new values. I am currently using an infinite loop to check for this within a new thread, will this be using a lot of resources/is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: you can send the broadcast to your activity from the service

Comment: You need a simple callback.  Polling a global variable for changes is definitely something you should avoid.  I can only be as specific as the code you're posting, but Services have build in ways to broadcast a change to anyone that has registered for updates.

Comment: you are basically asking about how to communicate between a Service and Activity. Search on SO, you will find tons of stuff on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a broadcast from the Service to send the changes in the variable. First of all create a broadcast in your main Activity.

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Broadcast","broadcast received");
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("Variable"); // this will get the value 
                                                          // send from Service
    }
};
```

Next set a intent filter to which the broadcast listens. This you can do in `onCreate()` of your activity.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("FROM_SERVICE");
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
```

then in your service you must send a broadcast. If you want to send some data from Service to Activity then you must replace the above code with below

```
Intent intent = new Intent("FROM_SERVICE");
intent.putExtra("Variable", "change");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: @user3023751 try it and if it solves your problem then mark the answer. And some FYI for you, upvote the answer if it helps you. Happy Coding !!!